# Raspberry Pi calling Python script from Ajax

Tags: python, ajax

I have a simple python code to test out, test.py

```
import random
pressure = random.random() * 8
displacement = random.random() * 70
```

I want to add a simple AJAX code to my .html file to execute this test.py

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "~/test.py",
data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   // do something
});
```

but it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Raspberry Pi, Raspbian, Apache server

Comment: have you configured your web server to execute your *.py scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Flask to serve:

your test.py code:

```
import random
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask import make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    ret = {
       'pressure' : random.random() * 8,
       'displacement' : random.random() * 70,
    }
    resp = make_response(jsonify(ret))
    resp.headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',  '*')
    return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

then you run it:

```
$ pip install Flask
$ python test.py
* Running on http://localhost:5000/
```

and in the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:5000/test",
data: { param: text}
}).done(function( o ) {
   // do something
});
```